# Check if property is null in lambda expression

Tags: c#, listview, lambda

I have a list of objects that I am trying to bind to a listview. I am sorting by two properties. The problem exists whereby some records may not have one of the properties. This is causing an error. I would like it to still bind the records that have the property.

```
IEnumerable<ERec> list = retailerList.Cast<ERec>();
lvwRetailStores.DataSource = list.OrderByDescending(r => r.Properties["RS_Partner Type"].ToString())
                                 .ThenBy(r => r.Properties["RS_Title"].ToString());
```

Comment: Do you want records missing the property to be at the beginning or end of the sorted list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list.Where(r => r.Properties["RS_Partner_Type"] != null && r.Properties["RS_Title"] != null)
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Properties["RS_Partner Type"].ToString())
    .ThenBy(r => r.Properties["RS_Title"].ToString());
```

Or instead of != null, use whatever test the Properties collection has.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the ?? Operator works well. I use Parenthesis to evaluate for null,

For Example:

`Datetime? Today = DateTimeValue
// Check for Null, if Null put Today's date
datetime GoodDate = Today ?? DateTime.Now`

This same logic works in Lambda, just use parenthesis to ensure that the correct comparisons are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary expression in the lambda:

```
list.OrderByDescending(r => r.Properties["RS_Partner_Type"] == null ? null : r.Properties["RS_Partner Type"].ToString())
    .ThenBy(r => r.Properties["RS_Title"] == null ? null : r.Properties["RS_Title"].ToString());
```

Comment: I should note, once the lambdas start getting that long it's a good idea anyway to declare them as functions to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another common approach is to give the collection a suitable default value, and return that when the collection doesn't have a particular key. For instance, if `Properties` implements IDictionary,

```
public static class IDictionaryExtension {
    public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue default) {
        TValue result;
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out result) ? result : dflt;
    }
}
...
lvwRetailStores.DataSource = list.OrderByDescending(r => r.GetValue("RS_Partner Type", "").ToString())
                                 .ThenBy(r => r.GetValue("RS_Title","").ToString());
```